# SQL query in two tables (1-M)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is called, bill and the other bill details. It has a 1-M relationship.

bill [1] ---- [M] bill_detail

How to make a query that shows me all the bill listings and the details of the bill_detail table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you 1) show us sample input and output data for these two tables, and 2) tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Hi ! The tables only have the respective id, the one that is related many has a foreign key. I use Mysql.

Comment: Read up on JOIN and search for mysql join two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b.id, bd.*
  from bill b
  join bill_detail bd
    on b.id = bd.id
```

Although, I have assumed column names, but kindly alwsys provide all details regarding the question so as to get better answers.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from bill innerjoin bill_detail where bill.x = bill_detail.x

In here, x is your joining condition. i.e it might be bill_id.

Hope this helps